# Service startup enigma: Timeout (error 1053), random, on computer startup

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a .Net Windows service that starts everyday just fine on hundreds of computers.

But the same service regularily (and randomly) fails on 4 of them, **on computer startup**:

> Error 1053: "The service did not respond in a timely fashion"

I know this error **may be caused by long running service init, or initialization failure.**
But i've done everything to be sure it was **not the case**:

1. The same service runs just fine (and starts instantly) when ran manually after startup
2. There is a big try/catch around service initialization caught with a File.WriteAllText() as a fallback if every other logging method fails... i dont see any log except the "timeout" in event viewer.
3. Initialization (i.e. service ctor) does nothing (no network calls, nothing which is not in-memory)
4. `OnStart` method is just `Task.Run(DoOnStart);`
5. Service runs as `LOCALSYSTEM`
6. I've configured my service to be dumped in case of process failure. No dump so far  (reg key in `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\MyService.exe`)
7. My `Program` class uses no fancy type, has no static ctor, thus cannot throw a `TypeInitializationException` before running Main (it would generate a dump anyway).

... No log, no trace, no dump, just a "timeout". Only on windows boot. It's just as if the process has never been launched. I'm a bit out of ideas to investigate further.

**Does anybody know about such a scenario, or a clue that might help me to dig deeper ?**

**[edit]** PS: Please read carefully before flagging as duplicate :) Ive read dozens of issues, none of them fits my problem.

**[edit 2]** The only culprit I already thought about was an antivirus. Is there any way for an antivirus to prevent a service startup ? (but this is a random guess, as the antivirus is just fine when I start it later, and I cant find any trace of AV activity)

Comment: Does your service have any dependencies on other services to be running? For instance, are you utilizing MSMQ and have your service set up with a "running" dependency for that service?

Comment: @gmiley Nope. Pure .Net :/